Is it possible to implement Label encoding/one-hot encoding categorical data-conversion in Einstein studio(Salesforce BYOM)
Question : Can we do the "label encoding / one-hot encoding" method of converting categorical data into numerical data on data cloud level / Einstein studio(creating model using salesforce BYOM). To my knowledge, I didn't observe these methods in these two platforms. If anyone have an idea , please help in answering this.

BYOM is bringing your own model. If you are using DataBricks, Vertex or Amazon Sagemaker you should be able to do all there and simply create endpoint within Salesforce to consume model predictions.

@MohithShrivastava - Thanks for response. As per your response, I understand one-hot encoding/label encoding is not possible, in einstein studtio. So, once we encoded the values from third party tools. We are not able to select catergorical data while preparing data in Model builder page in einstein studio. Do you have any idea of this issue, if yes, can you please help.

Can you elaborate a bit more with screenshots of possible?

Not sure, how to attach screenshots, here. Not finding any option to attach

You can edit the question and attach it and make it clear.
